# Flex application and shortcuts from IE 11.0.41

Tags: internet-explorer, apache-flex, keyboard-shortcuts, internet-explorer-11

I have a Flex 3 web application with some defined shortcuts.
All shortcuts work well until IE 11.0.40 update. From IE 11.0.41 these ones no longer work :

```
 CTRL+ALT+J
 CTRL+ALT+A 
 CTRL+ALT+C
 CTRL+SHIFT+H
```

I'm using WIN 10.
Are these new shortcuts of IE ? I haven't found any documentation about changes to the management of shortcuts.